# How to have multiple chunks but a single js file that loads them

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-splitchunks, splitchunksplugin

I'm trying to setup Webpack, currently not using dev-server and my app is being served by a python backend which has the index.html.

I'm trying to use the SplitChunksPlugin so that I can have multiple chunks (app, vendor, runtime, etc). However, to simplify how it loads from the python backend, I was wondering if there is a way I can tell Webpack to create an extra file, something like main.js which will dynamically load the other chunks in the right order. Is that a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [dynamic import](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports)

`import(/* webpackChunkName: "chunkName" */ 'chunkPath')`

Creating custom chunk and import it when it's needed and your file `chunkPath` may contain the other chunks you want to split, and it won't be loaded immediately.

from webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-):

> `import('path/to/module') -> Promise`
>
> Dynamically load modules. Calls to import() are treated as split points, meaning the requested module and its children are split out into a separate chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the html plugin to generate a js file that loads all the initial scripts:

```
      // Generate js entrypoint for the app to be loaded using a script tag
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        alwaysWriteToDisk: true,
        inject: false,
        // If you have multiple entry points and only some should be loaded 
        // this way, list those entry points in the chunks config
        // chunks: ['sdk'],
        filename: '[name].js',
        minify: false,
        templateContent: ({ htmlWebpackPlugin }) => {
          return (
            dedent`
            "use strict";
            (function(m) {     
              var baseUrl = new URL(m.publicPath, document.currentScript.src);        
              m.js.forEach(src => {
                document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('script'), { src: new URL(src, baseUrl).toString() }));
              });
              m.css.forEach(href => {
                document.head.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement('link'), { rel: 'stylesheet', href: new URL(href, baseUrl).toString() }));
              });
            ))(
          ` +
            JSON.stringify(htmlWebpackPlugin.files, null, 2) +
            ');'
          );
        },
      }),
```